# Is it possible to copy all data from one table to another table, plus an extra column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables that are very slightly different.  Table A has 4 columns, and Table B has only 3.  I want to copy all the data from Table B into Table A, but I also want to populate the extra column with the value `1` for every row.

This would work if not for the extra column:

```
insert into TABLEA (COL1, COL2, COL3) select COL1, COL2, COL3 from TABLEB;
```

Unfortunately, the extra column in Table A is not nullable, so I can't just run an update afterwards.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Specify the column and use a constant for the value (note you can mix constants and column references in a select clause). In this case we're specifying every row will get the constant `1` for column `COL4`.

```
insert into TABLEA (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)
select COL1, COL2, COL3, 1
from TABLEB;
```

Comment: Nice answer but no explanation of the syntax? What does the "select" part do o_O... someone who sees this for the first time is gonna have some questions...

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into TABLEA (COL1, COL2, COL3, extra) 
select COL1, COL2, COL3, 1 
from TABLEB;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO tableA SELECT a.*,<VALUE FOR THE EXTRA COLUMN> FROM tableB a
```

For example, if the extra column in `tableA` is `sys_creation_date` then

```
INSERT INTO tableA SELECT a.*,sysdate FROM tableB a
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO tableA SELECT a.*,'10-Jan-2013' FROM tableB a
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
insert into TABLEA (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) select COL1, COL2, COL3, 'Whatever' as COL4 from TABLEB;
```

Works on my computer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can select a constant from `TableB`

```
INSERT INTO tableA( col1, col2, col3, col4 )
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, 1 col4
    FROM tableA
```