# Insert values from a different table with a new column with constant value in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am inserting all values from a table into another table, which is created on the fly. I want to insert one extra column with constant value to the new table I create.

I have my `FinSls` table like this,

```
Time             Terminal_ID   Count
------------------------------------
2017-10-19 06:03:00     1       5
2017-10-19 06:04:00     1       2
2017-10-19 06:05:00     1       2
2017-10-19 06:06:00     1       2
2017-10-19 06:03:00     9       2
2017-10-19 06:04:00     9       3
2017-10-19 06:05:00     9       2
2017-10-19 06:06:00     9       3
```

I am creating a new table `BinTable` and I want to add a column `cons_val`  with a constant value, for example: 1, like this,

```
Time              Terminal_ID  Count  Cons_value
------------------------------------------------
2017-10-19 06:03:00     1       5      1
2017-10-19 06:04:00     1       2      1
2017-10-19 06:05:00     1       2      1
2017-10-19 06:06:00     1       2      1
2017-10-19 06:03:00     9       2      1
2017-10-19 06:04:00     9       3      1
2017-10-19 06:05:00     9       2      1
2017-10-19 06:06:00     9       3      1
```

So far I have my script like this,

```
select *
into  
   BinTable
from 
   FinlSls
```

How can I add a new column `Cons_Value` into my `BinTable`? I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089513/is-it-possible-to-copy-all-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-plus-an-extra-c) that already has the table created and then inserting value. But in my situation, how can I do this?

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 4):

You just add it:

```
select f.*, 1 as cons_value
into BinTable
from FinlSls f;
```

There may be some criticism in using `select *` instead of listing out the columns.

Comment: i like using declare @const [define exact data type you want] = [value]. This avoids all the different possible data types 1 can be (bit small int int big int etc)

Comment: @KeithL I agree about datatype but you don't need to use a variable for that. Simply use CONVERT(YourDataType, 1) instead of just the literal 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat it like any other `INSERT` statement and choose which columns are inserted into. In addition, you can choose which columns are selected, which allows you to joins as well.

It's good to define the table first, to ensure you create primary keys etc, I thought this was already being created as part of your process. I'm assuming this is a one time deal, in which case you would want tables indexed properly. If this was a temporary table for use in a stored procedure, then I would suggest using a temporary table (begins with a #).

```
CREATE TABLE
   [BinTable]
(
   [BinTableID] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   [Time] DATETIME,
   [Terminal_ID] INT,
   [Count] INT,
   [Cons_val] INT
);
```

Then you can insert the data.

```
INSERT INTO
   [BinTable]
([Time], [Terminal_ID], [Count], [Cons_value])
SELECT
    [Time], 
    [Terminal_ID], 
    [Count],
    1 AS [Cons_value]
FROM
    [FinSls];
```

Comment: I do not have`BinTable` created already, I am creating it on the fly as mentioned in the question. This statement needs the tables created beforehand

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: You can create a table immediately before, rather that implicitly creating one with a `SELECT ... INTO ...` I assume you are also going to be dropping the table at the end then?

Comment: Depending on your application, you may want to look at just using a view and essentially using a derived table. I would check both performance metrics https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897323/what-to-use-view-or-temporary-table

Answer (score 0):

If the new table already exists, use INSERT SELECT, else you can use the code below

```
SELECT Time, Terminal_ID, Count, 1
INTO BinTable
FROM FinlSls
```

Comment: This won't work for an existing table, as `SELECT ... INTO...` creates a new table.